# React Native Release: Could not connect to development server

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I followed the [official guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html) to create an installable Android application.

However when installing the APK with `./gradlew installRelease` the App crashes as soon as my React Fragment is loaded:

```
RuntimeException: Could not connect to development server.
```

My Fragment code looks like this, like the [Integration to Android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html) tutorial suggests.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getActivity().getApplication())
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
            .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(false) // changes nothing
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build();
    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "HelloWorld", null);
    return mReactRootView;
}
```

Do you have any ideas what I might do wrong? Does React Native need a development server even if the App is packaged for release? I can`t believe that.. I just want to get my App running as is.

Comment: I can confirm that it does NOT require a development server in release mode so there is something up with how you created the release. Before you ran the installRelease command did you run the assembleRelease command?

Comment: Yes, I did. I have react-native 0.29.0

Answer (score 0):

As @rmevans9 mentioned in comments above, you need not have development server for release or development mode (you are using offline bundling capability then).

One interesting point you mentioned in the code:

```
.setUseDeveloperSupport(false) // changes nothing
```

If you set it to true, does the app work by connecting to the local server? If not, my guess is that the react application you are using isn't registered as "HelloWorld" which you are using in the app invocation.

```
 mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "HelloWorld", null);
```

Make sure the name matches with what is registered in your react native app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My app is working fine with my development server, yes. You mean my component's name? 
`AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorld', () => HelloWorld);`

Comment: "Could not connect to development server." error implies it's not able to find the bundle. Are you sure it's the assets folder? [That link doesn't talk about that... hopefully you have run the command react-native bundle to copy the bundle.

Comment: Thanks for that comment. I just found out that indeed my bundle was not generated due to a different project structure (Android Default). Would you like to create a more comprehensive answer that I will accept? Otherwise I will.